# How to create an empty XML file from schema in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, xsd

I'm new to IntelliJ but I am trying to create an 'empty' XML file based on an [OSGi blueprint schema](https://osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd). In Netbeans this is is as simple as specifying a new file in the project, selecting type 'XML' and optionally specifying the (external) schema location.

But how do I do this in IntelliJ? I have added the external schema location in 'Settings' but I cannot find a way to create a new XML file and specify this schema.

I've looked through the IntelliJ documentation and it mentions [creating an instance document from a schema](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/generating-instance-document-from-xml-schema.html) by having the `.xsd` file open, but this seems a 'clunky' way of doing things, isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: What is "clunky" about it? You need to specify the schema to use, which element in that schema to use, and where to create the XML file. The dialog has appropriate defaults so you don't have to say much at all. How do you envision it begin less "clunky" than that? Seems pretty simple and easy to use to me.

Comment: Also consider that there is not a 1-to-1 mapping from a schema and possible XML documents conforming to that schema.  Whenever there are choices or cardinalities > 1 what should the generator do?  This is like asking for a list of valid English sentences given a dictionary plus syntax and grammar rules.

Comment: That's a fair point, Jim, but all I wanted was a 'blank' i.e. minimal XML document based on the specified schema, i.e. the XML name-space, schema location... Netbeans can do this so I was hoping IntelliJ could as well.